# PCLZIP_ERR_BAD_FORMAT (-10) : Unable to find End of Central Dir Record signature

Tags: php, zip

I'm using the pclzip class to autoupdate, and it keeps giving me this error when I try to run an auto update.

```
PCLZIP_ERR_BAD_FORMAT (-10) : Unable to find End of Central Dir Record signature
```

It has never given me problems before. I use the windows 7 'send to compressed zip folder' command. I've rezipped and re-uploaded countless times. I have this at the top of my update script to allow larger transfers:

```
ini_set("memory_limit","228M");
```

My only leads is that potentially my host might be running out of disk space, whcih I dont believe it is because my users are also having problems.

Any light?

Comment: Make sure the archive you are trying to extract is the same as the one you are sending.

Check the file size down to the bytes, or better yet, check its MD5 or SHA1 hash.